# mysqli prepared statements with between clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

My question is similar to [this][1] but the solution provided there doesn't work for me.
I have a DB and I have one column called `birth` that contains a date in the format `year-day-month 00:00:00`. Now I want to extract from the DB all the records which birth is between two dates. 
The `birth` value has been inserted in the DB with this code

```
$date =  $day . "-" . $month. "-" . $year;
$a = strptime($date, '%d-%m-%Y');
$DB_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900));
```

To extract the dates I am using this code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM database WHERE `birth` BETWEEN ? AND ?');
$start_date = '1990-01-01';
$stop_date = '1995-01-01';
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$start_date,$stop_date);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

but it doesn't find anything so `$result->num_rows` is equal to `0` and it doesn't give any errors so the problem must be in the comparison of the dates.

Comment: can you show some example data from your table? (and by the way: why y-d-m and not the iso-standard y-m-d, which has the benefits of being sortable and not confusing people?)

Comment: is your column birth a of the type DATETIME, or is it just a VARCHAR column where you store the date in that format?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The type of `birth` is `date`

Comment: That doesn't match up with your example, you can't store a time in a DATE column.

Answer (score 0):

Birth column format is y-d-m hour min sec. But in your where clause you are ignoring hour minute second factor.

Replace:

```
$start_date = '1990-01-01';
$stop_date = '1995-01-01';
```

With this:

```
$start_date = '1990-01-01 00:00:00';
$stop_date = '1995-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Kindly try it and let me know if it works

Comment: That's irrelevant for a DATETIME column.

Comment: if field type is datetime then you must compare between DATETIME values not only DATES.

Comment: The data type of `birth` is `date`. Putting the hour on the dates doesn't make any difference, the behavior is the same as before...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

The code in my question works if the data type of the column in the DB is `datetime` and you also need to make sure that `$start_date` is older than `$stop_date`. I still wonder though why it didn't work with the `date` data type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found another thread with the same problem (not sure how to duplicate this thread) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964274/how-to-write-a-prepared-statement-in-php-for-a-select-between-mysql-query-betwee)
However just to sum up,

They managed to get the desired results by bracketing the question marks for the params.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM database WHERE `birth` BETWEEN (?) AND (?)');
$start_date = '1990-01-01';
$stop_date = '1995-01-01';
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$start_date,$stop_date);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Hope this helps.